# Socket.io: Failed GET requests in the console

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, socket.io, client

I am trying to add socket.io to my code, and the following failed GET request is repeatedly printed to the console whenever I run the website on my localhost.

```
GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMNC8I9 0 ()
```

I do not understand what is sending this request. The socket works, although not entirely in the way I intended it to*.

*I am trying to build a real-time application that works with several clients, and at the moment only one client is being updated at any given time. As I am still learning, I am not sure if this is a normal behaviour or not, but I want to fix the failed request error before I dive into that!

How do I fix the issue? Thank you in advance!

Code below:

server.js

```
const client=require("socket.io").listen(4040).sockets;
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/<dbname>?replicaSet=rs'); 
mongoose.connect(config.db); 
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log(">>> ️  MongoDB: Connection successful");
app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Node server running on port 9000');
  });

// Connect to Socket.io
client.on("connection", function(){
let queries = db.collection('queries');

// Create function to send status
sendStatus = function(s) {
  socket.emit("status", s);
 }
  });
  });

app.post('/query', (req, res, next) => {
   <some code omitted> 
   doc.save()
     .then(result => {
     socket.emit("query", res);
     res.send({
     result
     });
   }
});
```

Queries.js

```
constructor(props) {
...
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000/");

if (socket!= undefined) {  
  socket.on("query", function() {
    this.loadQueries();
  });
}
```

index.html

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: It appears your socket.io client is v2.0.4.  Are you 100% sure that your server version of socket.io is the exact same version?  Mismatched versions can cause socket.io to regularly poll instead of connect an actual webSocket.  Also, why are you running socket.io on a different port from your web server.  That is not required and it complicates things.

Comment: This seems wrong: `const client=require("socket.io").listen(4040).sockets;`.  It seems like you want `const io = require("socket.io").listen(4040)` and then `io.on('connection', ...)`.

Comment: Your `connection` handler on the server, refers to a variable `socket` that is not defined anywhere.  Where does that come from in  your real code?

Comment: Also your `app.post()` handler refers to a `socket` variable.  That is likely not correct either.  I'm guessing that you're stuffing some `socket` into a module level variable and that's why it only works with one connection.  Can't do that in a server environment that serves the needs of many clients.  We would have to see much more of your real code to see the whole picture.

Comment: Also, you are making things more complicated than required by running your socket.io on a different port than your web server.  They can easily share the same port.